# getting name attribute dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div block where I am trying to find the name of the input element which was clicked and then update the value using jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="text" name="name1" id="id1">TestData1</input>
<input type="text" name="name2" id="id2">TestData2</input>
</div>
```

When I try to find the input element which was clicked I get `undefined`.

I am assuming it may be because I am checking click event on this and then again trying to get the `attr` name of it, but since it can increase to at least 5 input elements and these are being fetched dynamically, I cannot bind the id/class with click event.

Comment: Just a heads up.. `<input` tags are self-closing.. like so `<input type="text" name="name1" id="id1" />`

Comment: Use event delegation since you say you get elements dynamically.. `$(document).on('click','input', function...`

Comment: The value of `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbb1vt8w/), then right-click and hit Inspect.. go to console.. and click in the textboxes

Answer (score 3):

The `this` has no context inside ready function :

```
$(this).click(function(){
_^^^^^___________________
   console.log($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

You should use `input` :

```
$('input').click(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

**NOTE ALSO :** the input tag is self closed :

```
<input type="text" name="name1" id="id1" value='TestData1'/>
<input type="text" name="name2" id="id2" value='TestData2'/>
```

I hope this will helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="text" name="name1" id="id1" value='TestData1'/>
<input type="text" name="name2" id="id2" value='TestData2'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not bind by element instead?

```
$("input").click(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the click to `document`(Simply entire web page) and document doesn't have attribute called `name`. It will return `undefined` on console.

As other answers suggests, I'll also suggest binding click event to `input` instead of `document`.

If you want to bind click with `document` and find the target clicked element by using `event` which will be automatically available as an argument on click handler. Try with following snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(this).click(function(event){
    console.log($(event.target).attr('name'));
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" name="name1" id="id1">TestData1</input>
  <input type="text" name="name2" id="id2">TestData2</input>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here you access event target element on which you clicked and using it to get `name` attribute value. It returns `name` attribute value if your target element has `name` attribute else `undefined` will be returned.